# Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT Error

Tags: swift, messaging

I am working on an app where you click a button and it sends an already filled in text message and whenever I click the button it brings up the error...

I imported the messageUI framework and added the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate class as well.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.value) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
        println("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
        println("Message failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
        println("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the device you're testing on can send a message? The simulator doesn't have text message capabilities. Try this:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == false {
        println("Cannot send text")
        return
    }

    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: if !MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() { ... }